# How to inject database connection factory service into Jersey application

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jersey

I have a jersey application that i'm writing unit tests for testing my dao methods and it's proving to be extremely complicated for injecting a dependency when my app runs.

Here's my web.xml. You can see i'm using package scanning

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>my.package.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>
        my.package
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/v1/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have a controller with a method to handle a URI. This method calls my dao method which looks like this:

```
public class Dao {
    // I use a datasource when my app runs on tomcat, but for unit testing I spin up an in memory database and run my unit tests against that. Can't set a datasource for an in memory database
    public static final String DATASOURCE_NAME = "jdbc/myDataSource";

    // Dependency to be injected
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;

    public void setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }
...
```

I have a unit test which simply does this:

```
Dao dao = new Dao();
dao.setConnectionFactory(new DriverManagerConnectionFactory("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mymemdb:user=SA;"));
...
```

and I can easily run my unit tests. The problem is that now my app is broken b/c I don't know how to inject my DataSourceConnectionFactory when the app is started up or when a controller method is called through a URI.

The Jersey documentation is all over the place, vague, and doesn't provide any real examples that I'm able to follow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jersey 2.x, as far as I can tell they cover dependency injection to jersey resources here:  https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html

To be honest with you, for small apps using jersey I roll my own dependency injection with factories rather than use JSR-330 annotations or other DI mechanism.  My jersey resource constructs an instance of a POJO (say AccountManager) to do the work, the POJO constructor has dependencies on it (like IAccountDAO, say), and the jersey resource just goes to a POJO factory to get the dependency.  This makes the AccountManager POJO in this example easy to unit test because it is provided a DAO in the constructor rather than being directly coupled to one, doesn't require a DI framework and annotations to creep through the code.  Basically it's still DI but without the framework.  I'd only do it for pretty small apps - I just feel like hitting every app with Google Guice or Spring DI can be a bit overkill - the concept of DI existed before those tools did.

A sample jersey resource below.

DependenciesFactory is a POJO that builds the class with dependencies appropriately for your environment.  For instance, if the "TeacherDirectory" needs a datasource injected to it, or a DAO injected to it that in turn has a datasource injected in it, the factory handles that.  You have to think about singleton or not to singleton yourself a bit when you do this, but that's very manageable.  You also often need a way to tell what environment you are in - or at least maybe local developer box vs. deployed - which is true with any DI as well.  DIs can manage multiple configurations, so if you need multiple configurations and are rolling your own by hand you need to handle that.

```
@Path("/teachers")
public class TeacherResource {
    private final ITeacherDirectory teacherDirectory;

    public TeacherResource() {
        this.teacherDirectory = DependenciesFactory.getTeacherDirectory();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Provider> getTeachers(@QueryParam("teacherId") String teacherId, 
                                       @QueryParam("firstName") String firstName, 
                                       @QueryParam("lastName") String lastName) {

        return this.teacherDirectory.findTeachers(teacherId, firstName, lastName);
    }
```

Comment: I agree with you. Can you provide a code example of how you'd go about doing this though?

Comment: @Catfish - sure - although again I would use some caution hand-rolling DI - for a very large application it can get cumbersome.  Stack overflow comment might not be best way for sample code - I'll add another answer later today with an example.

Comment: You should just edit your answer with some example code rather than writing another answer.

Comment: You aren't gonna believe this, but I put the above sample code on the wrong question yesterday.  Folks looking at that question must have wondered what the heck was wrong with me....